# Vim - open wrong path when I run command ':vs .' run in Vim

Tags: split, plugin-nerdtree

When I run the `:vs .` command in Vim for the current working directory window split, the parent directory opens, not the current directory.

Example:

```
A/B/C$ vi test.c
```

in Vim:

```
:vs .
```

Split window displays `/A` not `/A/B/C`

I think it seems like a NERDTree problem. But I can't find cause and solution.

Comment: Could you tell us what is the result of the `:pwd` command? I suspect that your current working directory is not set to `A/B/C` but to `A`.

Comment: FWIW, I'm in the (bad) habit of having `:set autochdir` so all my paths are relative to the current file. Works for me.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt :pwd command result : /A

Comment: @Friedrich After input command `:set autochdir`, opens normally in that directory, but cannot be moved to the parent directory.

Comment: What do you mean by: cannot be moved to parent directory?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt If I try to move to the upper path in the divided window, it is impossible to move with the log as below.
'NERDTree: cannot close tree root
'

Comment: Could you share a screen shot? I believe it will help me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The `:vs .` open NERDTree at the current working directory (you can discover what the folder is with the `:pwd` Vim command).

By default Vim does not change the current working directory when you switch buffer or open a new file.

Vim set it at startup to the:

- The current working directory or
- The parent folder of the argument file if any

Youcan change the working directory with the `:cd` command or the buffer working directory with the `:lcd` command.

You can ask Vim to change automatically the current working directory to the folder that contains the buffer file with the `autchdir` setting:

```
:set autochdir
```

There are a number of plugins that can automatically set the current working directory using a logic (e.g. The parent folder that contains a `.git` folder or `.gitignore` file)

Some example are:

- [Startify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify)
- [vim-rooter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter)

Comment: Installing the 'Startify' tool that you told me does not solve the problem. Splitting in vim still opens the parent path.